# JavaScript doesnt work on Kohana with google maps engine line

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kohana

```
   <div style="width: 1200px; height: 750px;">
    <iframe src="http://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zkh_WUG-PAC0.k8Xr_3BhSQ00" width="640" height="480"
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        function load() {
            /* Проверка на совместимость с используемым браузером*/
            if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                /* Создать точку - центр */
                var pntx=37.62039542198181;
                var pnty=55.75294375419617;
                var center = new GLatLng(pnty, pntx);
                /* Создание объекта карты, googlemap - имя, по которому находится объект карты, описываемый ниже*/
                var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("mapgoogle"));
                            }
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
    > </iframe>
    ...
    <body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <div align="center"><div id="mapgoogle" style="width: 90%; height: 500px;"></div></div>
    </body>
</div>
```

a point does not take place on the center of map Аягоз, and not the alone from Javascript does not work! help to correct!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong code for your current API which is V3

Here's an example of how you could use it using your key:

```
var pntx = 35.62039542198181;
var pnty = 55.75294375419617;
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pnty, pntx);
var options = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), options);

var markerURL = "http://www.brouhaha.uk.com/wp-content/plugins/wild-googlemap/icons/marker-star-blue.png";

var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(markerURL,
new google.maps.Size(129, 52),
new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
new google.maps.Point(18, 42));

var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(pnty, pntx),
    map: map,
    icon: image
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function () {
    infowindow1.open(map, marker1);
});

var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: createInfo('Ibrahim El-Torbany','<a title="Click to view my page" href="https://www.facebook.com/S.1.L.Ibrahim.X.ElTorbany.S.1.L">My Page</a>')
});

function createInfo(title, content) {
        return "<div class='infowindow'><strong>"+title+" </strong>"+content+"</div>";
}
```

[API V3 Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vQPwc/2/)

Comment: Спасибо, но он тем не менее работает с моей ссылкой на карте, составленной мною в двигатель GM Lite ....<iframe src="http://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zkh_WUG-PAC0.k8Xr_3BhSQ00" width="95%" height="95%">  </iframe>